# How to iterate of web elements in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm learning cypress and i have such a test case: I have 12 buttons on web site and i'd like to check if every button is disabled. So i done this in that way:

Button: `<button id="add-product-5f188b5e68f9e" class="btn btn-sm" role="button" data-add-to-basket="" data-product-price="15.54" data-product-name="Okulary" disabled="">Dodaj</button>`

Here is my code :

it.only('T.C.1. - Add buttons-verifaction if all buttons are disabled when nothing is added', () => {

```
    cy.visit('https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1')
    cy.get('.caption').find('[role="button"]').should('have.length', '12').then( listOfAdds => {
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .first()
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(1)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(2)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(3)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(4)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(5)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(6)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(7)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(8)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(9)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(10)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
        cy.wrap(listOfAdds)
            .eq(11)
            .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
    })

})
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to do the same thing by using kind of iteration. Do You have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is much easier solution - using [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html). First, make sure there is 12 of them, then use `each()` to make sure each one of them has attribute `disabled`.

```
cy.get('.caption').find('[role="button"]').should('have.length', '12')
cy.get('.caption').find('[role="button"]').each((button) => {
    cy.wrap(button).should('have.attr', 'disabled')
})
```